# conversion rate, what should I count as a 'visitor'?

Tags: php, html, statistics, visitor-pattern

I want to implement visitors tracking on a php site, to estimate the conversion rates.
What every site tells me is that we should divide the the number of completed transactions to the number of visitos. But to what should we count as 'visitors' I haven't yet found a definite answer.

I may guess, there could be different methods, well let's talk about these that would be more reliable then, and provide for a more accurate calculation.

So, what is that? Should we take a number of let's say unique ips every day, or a number of pages loaded, or what? I'm completely lost, what should we track?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, so I'm afraid it doesn't really belong here.  This is a design issue.

Comment: Well, that's a technical issue, so guess it does! What we are is to find a way for an accurate calculation and calculation != design. Got it?

Comment: This is not on topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific _programming_ question, we'd love to help you. Determining the number of actual visitors your site gets by the number of requests your server processes compared to conversions can be done programmatically, but is not in and of itself a programming problem in the absence of an attempt on your part. However, this seems to be on topic at [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com), if you like I can migrate it there for you.

Comment: Oh, Actually I didn't know there were different sections... Definitely it should be placed in a right section then! Sorry for that. :)

Comment: @user1125062 Your question is about deciding what constitutes a visitor, not about how to calculate conversion from visitor data.  The former is very much a design decision, whereas the latter is the programming problem that you may need to solve once a decision on what constitutes a user has been taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only really useful metric is "Unique Visitors", specifically unique IPs that don't appear to be bots. The first part is easy but knowing what is and isn't a bot is a complex art. You should really leave this sort of tracking to a dedicated stats package like AWStats or Google Analytics (the later which has tools to track various sorts of goals and conversions).

If you really must have a DIY solution you should definitely start by looking at the browser/bot identification code in AWStats. I imagine that somewhere in there is a humungous list of known browser User Agent strings.

On many sites bots and crawlers can account for over 50% of actual "hits" or "pages" so if you can't identify bots accurately then your stats are basically worthless for most purposes.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense despite the lots of complaints alongside 'bout their 'inaccuracy', but let alone, what I'm worried about most, is - how would I then define into Google Analytics that there has been a conversion? Because the only way is to count the complete transactions from database, and not simply the visits to the checkout page... Please correct me if I'm wrong, isn't google analytics is just that? Counting pages? ...Please advice!

Comment: surely your checkout has a "thank you" or "order complete" page that you can use to determine if an order completed? If not just add one and tell GA it's the final step in one of your goals.

Comment: Oh, that get's interesting... :) But actually there isn't such page. The final page just get's the number of order, then it's up to user to call, come and claim it. Since it is the feature of the site - not to use any credit cards, or anything - simply order and pay with cash. I would gladly hear your ideas, if you've got a little time to share any of them. Thanks. :)

Comment: Well, actually, I can make just one such page, which would be technically visited as I click 'order complete' status in my admin panel. But they would all come from my IP then... Would it spoil the stats or would it do the trick?. ... Please advice.

Comment: You need to completely rethink how you approach this then. The only coherency you have between creating an order and completing it is your database records so you'll have to process them or create an event log.

Comment: Well, I can surely do whatever processing and programming is needed then. It's just about getting the whole thing automated now. Could you please tell some little more.. Should I then submit the data to Google, or should I process the google's data. Is there any way to make it automatic, or it can only be done manually?.. What would I do with logs?

Comment: I can't help you. Your question is too broad and there are too many answers. You'll just have to do more research at this point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal measure for web statistics. You can only compare against sites with similar measuring methods, and only then as a guide - never a definitive value.

You can measure trends on your own site if you use the same method for measuring from one month to the next for example.

In your case, I think daily unique visitors is the most useful, as it is probably closest to representing the actual number of visitors to a site.

Comment: THanks, it makes sense. I'm also quite a bit interested in a technical aspect.. do I guess that we just count unique IPs?

Comment: Any other ideas?? :) Or should I take this answer as an absolute truth? :P Tick tock...